# What are the hidden fees for using booking.com

Tags: money, payment-cards, fees-and-charges, price, booking.com

Trying to book a hotel using booking.com it states that "Additional charges may apply"

What are those charges?
How to calculate them?
Do I have to Pay them in cash?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 28):

It really depends and even Booking.com does not know which is why they use the word *may*. Generally speaking there are additional fees that they either cannot collect or cannot calculate due to complex rules that need more information than provided.

Sometimes there are no additional fees at all but often there is something charged by the locality. From the one example you show, Booking.com already calculated with local city tax which is included and known at the time. The last time I booked with them, the additional fee was 0.5 Eur per night which was a Tourist Tax with it being applicable to me as a tourist but probably not be applicable to someone local or on a different visa. Some hotels will collect them at check-in but most at checkout when you settle the bill which makes it easy to pay by card. I did not encounter a time when it was required to pay cash but that does not mean it is impossible.

To calculate them you can do some research about your destination but the more certain way to know is to just call the hotel in question.

Comment: If you get the bare minimum from a hotel using book.com you are lucky.   The room advertisements are at best misleading and highly inaccurate.   That being said knowing what the fees are and trusting that number is dumb.   At best it is a roll of the dice on if it will work out or not.   Some of the hotels (not all) are so dishonest that you can email them and ask them about fees - and with the printed confirmation from them they will still not honor it - 5 different hotels through booking.com.   So answering this is basically impossible.

Comment: @blankip, it may depend on location but I have never had to pay more than the advertised price (plus tourist tax) nor have I heard from friends that they were charged more.

Comment: Re tourist tax: I once would have had to pay a trivial amount of such a tourist tax in Germany. Only I was there on business, so it didn't apply to me - I just had to fill out a simple form stating the purpose of my trip. And of course booking.com or other channels can't know such details (or whether I'll even bother to spend half a minute filling out that form to save a few Euros).

Comment: @blankip Which country are your experiences from? I've used booking.com extensively throughout Europe and never once been charged more than stated on the booking

Comment: I've certainly paid a tourist levy (in France) on top of booking.com a couple of times. Often it's a requirement by the city for hotels to collect this directly. Sometimes if you go to the hotel's webpage (even after booking through booking.com) there will be a warning about this on their webpage.

Comment: Generally I have had very good experiences with Booking.com and only a handful of times got less than I expected. Most times I do read the reviewers before choosing one because some places seem horrible frankly but that's not the majority and I've used them in about 25-30 countries on every continent except Oceania and Antarctica (because I haven't been to either yet).

Comment: When I went to Las Vegas last year, I had to pay the $29 a night Raider tax (tourist tax to pay for the stadium) plus a $50 a night Resort fee - neither of which were included on any booking websites.

Comment: @HannoverFist Wow, that's outrageous. I don't recall anything of the like last time I was in Vegas (but that was like 6 years ago). Also, Raider tax - as in Oakland Raiders? Why the hell would you pay for them in Las Vegas????

Comment: @xLeitix, the [Las Vegas Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_Raiders) now.  However, quick search shows the Raiders tax at 0.88%, so either Hannover got a spectacularly expensive room, or it was a pure scam using legitimate fee names as an excuse to fleece much larger amounts.

Comment: @xLeitix - I checked and the $139.90 extra that we paid at checkout for the two nights above what we paid to the site (hotels.com?) was just listed as Resort Fee, Tourist Tax and Parking. I thought I saw or was told $29 though but it would have been about $6 based on user4556274's calculation.

Comment: @HannoverFist Ah, ok. Certainly expensive, but in my 10+ years of using hotels.com parking specifically can vary a lot - I have certainly paid 50 USD or more for 2 days of parking. Tourist tax is normally just a few dollars. I have heard that resort fees in Vegas can be very high.

Answer (score 19):

As booking.com states, requirements made directly to the hotel, like extra beds, cots for babies or pets allowed at extra pay, will be charged by the hotel.

Those are charges you should know about as you requested them or agreed to them.

Tourist tax is also to be paid directly to the hotel but is often already mentioned on the booking page.

An extra charge not yet know may be cleaning cost after illegal smoking or having pets in the room when not allowed.

How you pay these charges depends on the hotel, often they give you the options cash or cards but some only take one kind of payment, booking.com mostly mentions that in the hotel information on the booking page.

Cleaning charges can be taken through the credit card with which you secured the booking.